# If the sequence $(a_{n} \cdot b_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to 0, then...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

T/F: If the sequence $(a_{n} \cdot b_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to 0, then at least one of the sequences $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $(b_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to 0.

I'm trying to find two sequences that does not converge 0 but the multiplication of them does converge to 0. But it seems like every thing must include zero... any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 3):

Take $a_n=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 1& \text{ if }& n \text{ odd } \\ 
 0& \text{ if }& n \text{ even }
\end{matrix}\right.$

Can you now find $b_n$ so that $b_n$ does not converge to $0$ but $a_n \cdot b_n$ does ?